# Regex for reading strings separated by semi-colon and capturing special characters. Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as follows:

```
mod_str ="10Deamidated; 12Gln->pyro-Glu"
```

I want to separate the two parts of the string into elements of a list with tuples containing integer and string as follows:

```
[('10', 'Deamidated'), ('12', 'Gln->pyro-Glu')]
```

I am using the following code to capture the string but I am not sure how to include the special characters.

```
match_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)(\w+)')
items = match_pattern.findall(mod_str)
```

So far the output looks like this:

```
[('10', 'Deamidated'), ('12', 'Gln')]
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this regex?: `(\d+)([^;]+)`

The second group will capture one or more characters that are not semicolons.

Comment: If you don't want spaces to be captured, you could use `(\d+)([^;\s]+)`

Comment: Or add the special characters you want to support, escaping those that have special meaning in a character group, like `(\d+)([\w\->]+)`

Comment: @Dave Yarwood Thanks a lot! That's perfect.